# Dynamics Omnichannel different distribution method

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Can we have a different work distribution method (push - pick) for different queues in the same workstream? For example, I would like in the Facebook workstream to have the default messaging queue with push method and another queue where the agent can transfer the chats for someone else (or myself) to pick them later.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, dynamics omnichannel supports work distribution only at workstream level.